# Можно ли отправить запрос через guzzle без нумерации массива в query params?

Tags: php, laravel, запрос, guzzle

Всем привет и сразу к делу:
Шлю запрос через guzzle и при отправке соответственно добавляю query params

```
protected function send(Client $client, $request, array|null $getParams = null): ResponseInterface
    {
        $query = array_merge([
            'apiKey' => env('API_KEY'),
            'partnerId' => env('PARTNER_ID')
        ], $getParams ?? []);

        return $client->send($request, [
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
    }
```

Прежде чем отправить я соотвественно формирую реквест и обратите пожалуйста внимание, что в ф-ции ниже в send я передаю productIds[...] с данными

```
public function relatedRecommendations(string $sessionExternalId, $positionsIds)
    {
        $request = $this->request('get', '/api/3.0/productRecommendations/related', [
            'sessionExternalId' => $sessionExternalId,
        ]);

        $result = $this->send($this->externalClient, $request, [
            'link' => "{'name': 'sessionExternalId', 'value': '$sessionExternalId'}",
            'productIds' => $positionsIds
        ]);
        
        return array_map(function($item) {
            return $item->productId;
        }, (array) json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents())->recommendations);
    }
```

И вот как раз суть вопроса...опечалило то, что guzzle решил пронумеровать query params которые взял из массива(productIds0=...&productIds1=...):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Можно ли как-то передать эти параметры в таком же виде, но без этой нумерации от массива?**

UPD: Обновляю вопрос по комментариям. 1. Мне необходим формат ?productIds=...&productIds=... вот в таком варианте.
2. Необходим такой вариант т.к. именно такой вариант требует стороннее api с которым делаем интеграцию
3. Интегрируюсь с данным сервисом и как раз ссылка на запрос который вызывает трудности: https://docs.retailrocket.ru/reference/alternatives
UPD2: Также заметил такой момент, что нельзя чтобы url юзал что-либо из кодировок кроме UTF-8. Это проблема с которой я столкнулся когда решил первую

Comment: а чем вам мешают эти номера?

Comment: А как вы их хотите передать? Приведите, пример, пожалуйста. По вопросу пока не совсем понятно в чем именно проблема.

Comment: @newman либо просто `&productIds[]=....&productIds[]=...` либо не ясно о чем речь. Но разница в таком случае вроде быть не должно

Comment: Ну почему же - то что у вас в вопросе - это логичное и правильное поведение. То что хотите вы - это не очень логично. Не факт, что сервер, куда вы отправляете запрос, корректно его обработает.

Comment: @teran ,обновил вопрос

Comment: @newman , обновил вопрос

Comment: `x=1&x=2` тут вопрос к серверу, на апаче, например, это  вернет просто `x=2`. Возможно, какие-то вэб-сервера соберут в массив. но емнип массивы должны передаваться как `[]` и никак иначе

Comment: прошел по ссылке апи. у вас написано там список через запятую. при чем тут массивы? `'productIds' => implode(',' $productIds)`

Comment: при этом описание поля, `array of int`. косяк какой-то в описании.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [Query::build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547321/696034) для обертки массива параметров.

Answer (score 0):

`guzzle` для преобразования массива использует встроенную функцию `http_build_query` которая не имеет параметров для изменения такого поведения.

Можете либо самостоятельно сформировать `query` строку из массива, либо удалить индексы регулярным выражением:

```
$query = http_build_query($query, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
$query = preg_replace('/%5B\d+%5D/', '', $query);
return $client->send($request, [
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Comment: я бы убедился для начала, что вариант описанный в документации апишки, в виде стоки через запятую не прокатит, а потом бы уже костыли писал

Comment: @teran Вопрос был как убрать нумерацию, а не как использовать апишку

Comment: вопрос задается с тем чтобы решить проблему. Если автор неправильно ее решает, ответ должен прежде всего подсказать, как ее решать правильно, а не чинить некорректное решение, костылями